# Trying to add a JFrame through a action listener button JAVA Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing

When the user check marks the "Character" checkbox, and then when they hit enter it should add a JFrame, but for some reason it doesn't do anything. Help please!

```
  check1.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  chars = true;
               }
            });

  enter.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                  if(chars == true){
                     character = new JLabel("characters");
                     outputDisplay.add(character);
                     leftside.add(outputDisplay);
                  }
                  displayData();
               }
            });
```

Comment: What does displayData do? What is leftside? What is outputDisplay?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

> but for some reason it doesn't do anything.

What basic debugging did you do? What code is being executed?

Is the listener code invoked? Did you add a System.out.println(...) to see if the code is being executed?

> Trying to add a JFrame through a action listener button JAVA Swing GUI

What do you mean "add a JFrame"? I don't see you creating a new JFrame anywhere.

If you mean you are trying to add a component to a frame, then the basic logic should be:

```
panel.add( some component );
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

That is you need to invoke revalidate() to make sure the layout manager is invoked and then repaint() to make sure the panel is painted with the new component.